# UIScrollview height won't change programatically in swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

Try to change scrollview height, but it doesn't work programatically

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView : UIScrollView!

public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.frame.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea to solve this?

Comment: If you are using autolayout, you cannot change the height using frames. You will need to create an `outlet` to your `height constraint` and update the `constant` of that constraint programatically.

Comment: @ShawnFrank i set constant scroll height in view did appear. But when i build it,  scroll height start with constant height i defined (run correctly) ,but then the height back to normal again to height size in xib file

Comment: Please update your question by adding the code that would have suggested in your comment.

Comment: I think you are using Textview in scrollview. Textview has own scrollview so why you use extra scrollview? Is there a reason?

Comment: @LouisSant - is this the same, or almost the same, question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522276/vertical-scroll-not-work-in-uiscrollview-swift